# EditText unreadable when disabled on some devices

Tags: android, user-interface, user-input

I have a simple EditText field that shows a user's phone number on a login page.  After initial login the phone number field is disabled.

This looks great on almost all of my devices (this screenshot is from a Samsung Galaxy S):
[image]

However, on my LG Nitro the text in the disabled EditText field is unreadable (I can just about see the white text if I zoom in on a high res screenshot):
[image]

I removed all my custom style rules from the EditText and the same problem occurs, so I *think* this is just a bad choice of system default colors for the phone.

**Question 1:** Can anybody confirm if my diagnosis is correct?

The only way I could make the text readable was to set the text to dark grey in code:

```
if (fieldDisabled)
{
  // Some devices use their own default style for a disabled text field,
  // which makes it impossible to read its text, e.g. the LG Nitro.
  //
  // The workaround is to override the text color here.
  mPhoneNumber.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
}
```

Afterwards the text was easy to read on all devices (including the LG Nitro):
[image]

I to set my custom style to use `@color/black` instead of the existing color, but the text was still shown as white.

**Question 2:** Is there a better workaround I can use?

My LG Nitro is model LG-P930 running OS 2.3.5.

**My XML**

Below are snippets of the XML I am using.

res/layout/myscreen.xml:

```
<EditText
  ...
  android:textAppearance="@style/MyStyle">
</EditText>
```

res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
  <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

res/values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
<color name="blue">#ff0000ff</color>
<color name="black">#ff000000</color>
```

Comment: instead of disabling the edittext you can make focusable false for edittext after your initial state. So that it will not get focus & it will looks perfect

Comment: This is a good suggestion and did much of what I want.  FYI, I needed to call setFocusableInTouchMode(false) as well as setFocusable(false) to get it to work.  However, the downsides are that it messed up my focus logic (which I can fix), and more importantly the text field now looks like an enabled text field instead of a disabled one.

Comment: yes i think by which your problem is solved.... :)

Comment: I need the EditText to be readable, but I still want it to appear disabled.  I did figure out how to achieve this in my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to change the color of the EditText text.

Using `android:textAppearance` does **not** appear to allow you to change the color of the text in an EditText (it does let you change the text size).

One alternative is to use the `style` attribute instead of `android:textAppearance`, as that will apply the text color changes, e.g.

```
style="@style/MyStyle"
```

However, I think the best solution is to use a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html).  Below is my solution.

res/layout/myscreen.xml (still need textAppearance to control the text size):

```
<EditText
  ...
  android:textColor="@color/edittext"
  android:textAppearance="@style/MyStyle">
</EditText>
```

res/color/edittext.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/black" />
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

res/values/styles.xml (i.e. make MyStyle only define text size, not color):

```
<style name="MyStyle">
  <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
</style>
```